# C++ header dependencies

Tags: c++, header-files

I am trying to modify Android, wherein I am changing some of its C++ code, and am facing issue related to header includes.

Say in a file `foo.c`, I need to include the `bar.h` but it sits in a different folder:

`../../dir1/dir2/bar.h`

`bar.h` in turn includes a file `baz.h` from the same folder `(dir2)`:

`#include <dir2/baz.h>`

At first I tried to include `bar.h` as follows in `foo.c`:

`#include "../../dir1/dir2/bar.h"`

But them `bar.h` cannot find `baz.h`.

I tried to change the `Makefile` to add `INC=-I../../dir1`, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Have you tried dumping all compile flags gcc is using? I think there must be something like verbose mode in make

Answer (score 3):

Since bar.h and baz.h are in the same directory, use the following in bar.h:

```
#include "baz.h"
```

In order to `#include` bar.h in foo.c, you have many choices. E.g.

**Choice 1:**

```
#include "../../dir1/dir2/bar.h"
```

and compile with `-I.`. You may omit the `-I.` too.

**Choice 2:**

```
#include <bar.h>
```

and compile with `-I../../dir1/dir2`.

**Choice 3:**

```
#include <dir1/dir2/bar.h>
```

and compile with `-I../..`.

What method you choose for `#include`ing bar.h in foo.c depends on a larger view of how rest of your code is structured and your definition of modularity in the project.

Comment: For **Choice 1**, you don't actually need `-I` flag

Comment: @Zereges, indeed.